# Simplifying the Boolean binary equation

Tags: binary

A'B + A'B'C + ABC'C' + AB' + AB'C'

I need to simplify this boolean equation in simplest form but im not sure of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** One possibility is: $A'C + BC' + AB'$. Try drawing a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Otherwise, here's a quick sketch of a proof:

- $ABC'C'=ABC'$.
- $AB'C'$ can be absorbed into $AB'$.
- $A'B$ can be decomposed into $A'BC$ and $A'BC'$.
- $A'B'C$ and $A'BC$ can be combined to form $A'C$.
- $ABC'$ and $A'BC'$ can be combined to form $BC'$

---

**EDIT:** Here are the details.

$$ \begin{align*}
&A'B + A'B'C + ABC'C' + AB' + AB'C'\\
&= A'B + A'B'C + ABC' + AB' + AB'C' & \text{Idempotent Law} \\
&= A'B(1) + A'B'C + ABC' + AB' + AB'C' & \text{Identity Law} \\
&= A'B(C + C') + A'B'C + ABC' + AB' + AB'C' & \text{Inverse Law} \\
&= A'BC + A'BC' + A'B'C + ABC' + AB' + AB'C' & \text{Distributive Law} \\
&= (A'B'C + A'BC) + (ABC' + A'BC') + (AB' + AB'C') & \text{Commutative/Associative Law} \\
&= A'C(B' + B) + BC'(A + A') + AB'(1 + C') & \text{Distributive Law} \\
&= A'C(1) + BC'(1) + AB'(1 + C') & \text{Inverse Law} \\
&= A'C(1) + BC'(1) + AB'(1) & \text{Domination Law} \\
&= A'C + BC' + AB' & \text{Identity Law} \\
\end{align*} $$

Comment: A’B + A’B’C + ABC’C’ + AB’ + AB’C’=
A’B + A’B’C + ABC’ + AB’ + AB’C’=
A’(B +B’C) + ABC’ + AB’(C’+1)=

I'm stuck after this plz help me

Comment: @David I've edited in the details.